# juHow to find % of missing values which are greater than 1 or 0 in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am finding the percentage of missing values in my dataset with more than 0 or 1 as I want to impute it later.

I am using this code
df which has the data

```
df.isnull().mean()*100
```

output of the above code

```
loan_amount         0.000000
funded_amount       0.000000
investor_funds      0.000000
term                0.000000
interest_rate       0.000000
                    ...    
settlement_term    98.534284
year                0.000000
loan_condition      0.000000
region              0.000000
emp_length_int      6.438357
```

this code is giving me the percentage. Now as my dataset has more than 200 columns, it is difficult to get into my page, so I am unable to see whole result as well.

if I am doing this

```
df.isnull().mean()*100>0
```

it is giving me Boolean(true, false) which totally make sense to me. But here i need the numbers not the boolean.

The intent of the output is, I do not want the rows which say 0. But need all rows with greater than 0

Comment: Are you managing your dataset from the shell?

Comment: Also the comparison operators always return True or False. If you type 5 > 6, it will return False, because the condition is False (5 is not greater than 6).

Comment: @TechPerson No, I am managing in google colab

Comment: What is the intended output exactly?

Comment: @TechPerson modified the question little bit

Answer (score 0):

I don't personally use dataframes, but [this](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_selecting_rows_on_conditions/) seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. Posting for other's to get help from this.

We need to convert it to dataframes and make a column make first and then use the comparison operator >. Example-

```
df_1= pd.DataFrame(df_com.isnull().mean()*100,columns=['Percentage'])
df_1[df_1['Percentage']>0]
```

This will give you the desired output of missing % values with greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
missing_v = round(train.isna().sum()/len(train)*100,2)
missing_v[missing_v > 0]
```

Steps:

1. Save it into a df
2. Filter it.